# Why don't people edit questions to match their answers?

Tags: discussion

Why don't people with plenty of reputation edit questions to match their answers when the answer is based on the presumed intent of the question instead of what is actually written?

Often those answers are even accepted, leaving a totally disconnected question and answer pair for future visitors to enjoy. The trolling part of me prevents downvoting of such answers and there is absolutely no incentive for me to edit questions to at least remotely match answers.

Today's example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71375497/csc-langversion-is-not-working-in-vs-code - question "how to run CSC from VSCode", answers "this is how to compile .Net Core project without VS/VS Code". While I agree that it is what OP of the question probably needed and likely accept the answer this leaves a totally unhelpful pair.

Since there is no way to stop people from being helpful, would it be better to update the policy to strongly recommend editing the question to match the answer?

Comment: Just because OP chose to accept a not so great answer doesn't mean the question should be bend to match the answer and prevent future answers who actually answer the question in a proper manner. Such a recommendation could also result in overzealous users who post their answer and then alter the question to match their answer before OP responded. This is also troublesome when there are competing answers with competing interpretations of the core issue in the question.

Comment: Isn't the real question: Why do they answer already while the question needs editing?

Comment: Great, I can answer anything now. Just write my answer and then edit the question into matching whatever my answer was about.

Comment: Perhaps find a better example? The answer does not follow the [Help Center's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*

Comment: (The answer was deleted by the author on 2022-03-07T143618Z.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen That comment should be clarified to say that the answer was deleted by the question author when they deleted the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> [W]ould it be better to update policy to strongly recommend editing the question to match the answer?

No.

If the question is unclear (*i.e.* missing necessary information to answer) it should be closed, not answered.

---

#### Incorrect Assumptions

If someone believes the question *is* answerable, the assumptions made about the question should go in their answer, not the question<sup>1</sup>. If the answerer adds their own *assumptions* into the question, then the question is forever skewed. The primary concern is: what if that assumption is incorrect?

*Note I'm not speaking on cases where the asker's intent is clear, but is lacking some key terminology or formatting (standard editing reasons).

Beyond this, if this were a general rule, the potential that someone answers the question entirely incorrectly (their assumptions were incorrect) would be able to just edit the question to match their (wrong) answer. Which is something we do not want as this makes it so the OP doesn't get an answer to *their* problem and opens the door to a potential abuse of editing privileges.

#### Conflicts with current Editing Guidelines

Since we don't want a separate set of rules for users with full editing privileges vs users that need to suggest edits. That would mean that edits that update the question to match a user's answer would need to go through Suggested Edits Queue where the only (correct) action to take would be to reject as "Clearly conflicts with author's intent".

#### The One Exception?

Edits to make the question more clear may be acceptable if there is a lot of clarifying information in comments on the question and the answer. However, even in this case an edit that fundamentally changes the way the question was presented may invalidate the other answers on the question (which would need to be rejected or rolled back).

For this reason, the only case I can think of where this type of edit might be acceptable is on questions where there is a *single* answer, which is accepted by the OP (or otherwise indicted that the answer is correct *e.g.* comments), *and* there is additional clarifying information in the comments. However, in this case, the edit would just be summarising useful information missing from the question body, and not just overriding potentially useful information in the question with a different user's.

---

<sup>1</sup> (As a general rule) There may be exceptions